# Auto Renewal Subscription Wrong Expiration Date-Time

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, auto-renewable

After reading all the documents at Apple Website and couple of other resources I am not sure why the expiration time is just 8 hours ahead of purchase time for a yearly subscription.

Here is what the app receipt info is returning in lates_receipt_info Array.

```
"latest_receipt_info" =     (
                {
            "expires_date" = "2018-04-28 16:33:20 Etc/GMT";
            "expires_date_ms" = 1524933200000;
            "expires_date_pst" = "2018-04-28 09:33:20 America/Los_Angeles";
            "is_in_intro_offer_period" = false;
            "is_trial_period" = true;
            "original_purchase_date" = "2018-04-28 15:33:21 Etc/GMT";
            "original_purchase_date_ms" = 1524929601000;
            "original_purchase_date_pst" = "2018-04-28 08:33:21 America/Los_Angeles";
            "original_transaction_id" = 1000000394415263;
            "product_id" = "com.myapp.yearly";
            "purchase_date" = "2018-04-28 15:33:20 Etc/GMT";
            "purchase_date_ms" = 1524929600000;
            "purchase_date_pst" = "2018-04-28 08:33:20 America/Los_Angeles";
            quantity = 1;
            "transaction_id" = 1000000394415263;
            "web_order_line_item_id" = 1000000038589890;
        }
    );
```

The purpose is obviously to validate the subscription for reasons such as user cancelled the subscription or it cannot be renewed by any other circumstances.

Although I can validate this on every app launch but it is required that if user has purchased a subscription on iOS platform then he/she can access premium content on other platforms such as Web.

Comment: are you testing it in sandbox environment with test users?

Comment: Yes @VikasDadheech. Later on, I found out  that 1 year = 1 hour in sandbox environment.